# Comma-delimited request params not working with Kotlin data class

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I have an endpoint which can accept dozens of request params.  It would be nice to collect all these params in a data class.  Additionally, the request params must be separated by commas
`path?param=1,2`
to keep backward compatibility.
Assume we have this endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("path")
fun someFun(@RequestParam param: Set<Int> = emptySet()
   ...other 11 params
)
```

I created a data class to collect all the request params:

```
data class ClusteredParams(val param: Set<Int> = emptySet()
   ...other 11 params
)
```

So the endpoint looks like the following:

```
@GetMapping("path")
fun someFun(param: ClusteredParams)
```

When I called `path?param=1,2` I got:

> "error": "Failed to convert value of type java.lang.String[] to required type java.util.Set; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1,2"",
> "field": "param",
> "rejectedValue": "1,2"

When I call `path?param=1&param=2` everything is fine. **This problem does not exist when ClusteredParams class is written in Java**.

```
public class ClusteredParams {
   private Set<Int> param;
   ...other 11 params
   
   getters and setters
}
```

Comment: How does ClusteredParams look like in Java?

Comment: Try to wrap it with brackets. `path?param=[1,2]`

Comment: Try `param=1&param=2`

Comment: Did you guys read the post? What he needs to achieve is path?param=1,2 because that is possible in Java.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I added code sample

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer, but I did the comparison what works and when:

**in Java:**

You can either call `?path=1,2` and `?path=1&path=2` no matter if your request param is declared using `@RequestParam path: List<Int>` inside signature of controller method, or it is a field of external object that's used to group all request params of controller method.

**In Kotlin:**

if you declare your request param inside of controller method signature, as a `@RequestParam path: List<Int>` or whatever else, you can call it using both methods, so:

?path=1,2 and ?path=1&path=2

If you however extract it to separate data class, and then expect this class to be populated in controller method, you can only do the ?path=1&path=2, because in the case of ?path=1,2 you get:

org.springframework.validation.BindException because it tries to parse entire '1,2' instead of split it first.

I hope now it is more clear, does anyone have idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `val` use `var` inside data class body:

```
data class ClusteredParams(
   ...other 11 params
) {
   var param: Set<Int> = emptySet()
}
```